# PCB solder mask inconsistency

Tags: pcb, manufacturing, solder-mask

We have a small PCB that has been manufactured and assembled several thousand times. However, the last lot showed inconsistencies with the solder mask:

[image: Solder mask inconsistencies]

It looks like the solder mask is very thin, almost exposing the copper. The expected color would be what you see next to the SOT23 pads.

We contacted the PCB manufacturer about this, who claims that it is most likely an issue from too high soldering temperature or too long solder duration.

So we contacted the assembly company, but they say that the soldering process did not change from the previous runs and it must be a problem with the PCB manufacturing process.

1. Did anyone experience this kind of issue and what is the likeliest cause?
2. How critical is this? I can't quantify if I am looking at slightly less solder mask or nearly no solder mask at all.

Comment: Looks like the usual cheap crappy china PCB solder mask.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: The thing is that both companies were picked because they tend to be pretty reliable and are ISO 9001 certified, since this PCB is for automotive use.

Comment: even chinese fish markets are ISO9001 certified. Having worked in the aviation industry, I can tell you that this alone means nothing. It only means that you hold up to some self created standards, however low they might be. It doesn't mean that never fuck up products and try to sell it anyways. Or that you fucked up scheduling and outsource to someone else. To check who is right, you should just have a look at some unpopulated boards.

Comment: Off-topic question: is it standard practice to add thermal relief on the heat sink pads? It kind of defeats their purpose.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: I do not think the designer had heat sinking in mind but low impedance to the plane. I am not familiar with the circuit.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Indeed, ISO9001 doesn't prevent a manufacturer to sell crap. But the awesome is that, once certified, they can prove it's crap! Another thing that has always amused me: Once certified, the manufacturers pays ISO for the certification and each renewal. If not certified, there are no renewals to pay, of course... So, guess what ISO does?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Well maybe true, but that is not really the point here. Just assume for the moment that both are not sloppy companies per se and from our experience. Sadly, all PCBs were assembled in one run. I was just hoping for some feedback regarding the likely cause (manufacturing or assembly).

Comment: @Rev1.0: lets put it that way: I have never seen solder mask getting thinner or discoloured by soldering. Have you checked if its thin or discoloured btw.?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I would also tend to blame the manufacturer. Under the magnifier it looks just thin.

Comment: Do you conformal coat these PCBs after assembly? If so then this solder mask issue (while annoying) may not really be a problem.

Comment: @brhans: The PCB is only partially coated since some THT connections have to be soldered afterwards, when the PCB is mounted. We inspected some older unassembled PCBs (from the same manufacturer) that we found and while those are "better", I still wouldn't call the solder mask "good". So its pretty clear now, that its a manufacturing problem and we will confront them with that.

Comment: It could be the pigmentation within the solder mask was a little lower concentration than normal. So that effect could manifest itself with a lower thickness of material or a uniform thickness with different pigment loading or even both.  Best to see to see if you can measure actual thickness.

Comment: 1. Are you sure your PCB shop didn't just change what soldermask material they use? 2. Does your fabrication print specify a particular soldermask material and a minimum soldermask thickness? If not, then you've learned why you should do that.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Is is common to specify that? I mean you can't really rely on solder resist for isolation or coating purposes can you? Does it get relevant when calculating ultra high speed transmission lines? I don't know. In the end, the primary function is - well - to resist solder. So as long as the soldering result is OK, one could argue that its fine.

Comment: @Rev1.0, I've had customers who would reject parts if the soldermask color changed from dark green to light green, for example. And the fact that you asked your question implies that consistency of the soldermask is important to you. If you care about changes in the soldermask, then you should specify that in your prints.

Comment: @ThePhoton: True. The obvious visual difference between the PCBs just rang my alert bell, thus asking this question for some insights. In the future I would definitely consider that consistency is a requirement. Even if they the result is just within the specified production design limits, it indicates kind of sub-standard quality.

Answer (score 1):

We had a detailed discussion with the PCB manufacturer. Suffice to say, that they guarantee (according to their "Process and Capability Manual") a solder mask of at least 5um.

According to them, everything nearing the 5um thickness would already result in the "copperish" color shining through the solder resist.

The solder resists viscosity may vary slightly and cause differing results, especially at the edges, where some resist may flow off the copper.

Nevertheless we get better and more consistent results from other manufacturers, so it still stands that their processing quality may not be optimal.

Comment: The ultimate question is: Does it work?

Comment: I just saw a very similar issue to this with one of my designs at work. I ordered them from Advanced Circuits and they sent back boards with what looked to be bare copper in certain areas. It is fully-coated, it's just thicker in some places than in others. Despite the look, it still functions correctly.

Comment: @pipe: The boards tested so far are all working, but we did not expect any problems there.